# How to substitute dates in Perl?

Tags: perl, regex

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/2013/07/31-05:54:14/2014/07/31-00:00:00/g;' /tmp/ranjan/replace.SEL
```

I'm using the above one liner to replace the date from `2013/07/31-05:54:14` to `2014/07/31-00:00:00`. But I'm unable to do it. I'm able to find only substitution for string not for numbers which are in the above format . please help me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an [alternative delimiter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

```
s{find}{replace}g;
```

or

```
s#find#replace#g;
```

Otherwise you'd have to escape all the `/`.

Answer (score 4):

Perl thinks that the forward slashes in your dates are actually part of the substitution statement `s///g`, so you can either escape the slashes in your dates or use a different delimiter for your substitution

```
perl -pi.back -e 's/2013\/07\/31-05:54:14/2014\/07\/31-00:00:00/g;'
```

or more readable:

```
perl -pi.back -e 's#2013/07/31-05:54:14#2014/07/31-00:00:00#g;'
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your delimeter or you have properly escape your regexp strings.

The dilmeter could be anything non printable, i like to use !.

like this:

```
s!2013/07/31-05:54:14!2014/07/31-00:00:00!g;
```