# How to access and replace in perl?

Tags: perl

I have current server time in a variable and I need to replace `AT=2013/07/31-10:08:41` with the value that is present in my variable. How can I replace this in Perl?

```
get(J=tesr,T=Bp,Act=A_Ti,AT=2013/07/31-10:08:41);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927136/how-to-substitute-dates-in-perl/17927285#17927285

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitution operator, for more information about this operator refer to::

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html

You can find many tutorials on the net about this operator by a simple google search.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of substitution operator.. but in this case AT=2013/07/31-10:08:41 will not be constant.. each time i hv to fetch the value of AT and replace. How to fetch is wat i want to know!

Answer (score 0):

If you this as a string (maybe from a config file), this works:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = 'get(J=tesr,T=Bp,Act=A_Ti,AT=2013/07/31-10:08:41);';
$string =~ /AT=(.+)\);/;
my $new_time = 'new_time';
$string =~ s/$1/$new_time/;
print $string;
```

Of course, you have to replace 'new_time' with your server time. For the next time, please check your spelling first.

Answer (score 0):

That's one day of replacing the value of AT using a time that is set on another variable ( $new_time in this case )

```
my $str = "get(J=tesr,T=Bp,Act=A_Ti,AT=2013/07/31-10:08:41);";

my $new_time = "2013/08/01-02:05:24";

$str =~ s/(AT=)(\d{4}\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1])-([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/$1$new_time/g;

print "$str\n";
```